# Homomorphism from a commutative group?

Tags: graph-theory

I came across this question in a practice exercise and can't quite understand it.

If f is a homomorphism from a commutative group $(S,*)$ to another group $(T,*')$, then prove that $(T,*') is also commutative.

As far as I understand homomorphic functions don't have to be from a commmutative group to another commutative one. Am I not understanding something about the question?

Comment: Could it be that $f$ is *onto*?

Comment: Where did you see it? Does it say surjective homomorphism? Of course $T$ doesn't have to be commutative (otherwise). For example, $e \mapsto I, a \mapsto -I$ is a homomorphism from the commutative group $\{e, a\}$ to the non-commutative group $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ (let's say $n > 1$).

Comment: The question was copied exactly from a question paper. I guessed that they made a mistake but I wasn't sure. Thanks for confirming it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the homomorphism is *surjective*, you can show this directly. Let $f: S \to T$ be a surjective homomorphism and let $a, b$ be elements of $T$. Then there are $a', b'$ in $S$ such that $f(a')=a$ and $f(b')=b$ (this is where you need surjectivity). Thus $f(a'\ast b')=a\ast'b$. But since $S$ is commutative, $a'\ast b'=b' \ast a'$. Thus $f(a'\ast b')=b\ast'a$, which proves that $a\ast' b=b\ast' a$. Hence $T$ is commutative.